# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$offlineStorage' of undefined in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am using this plugin https://github.com/filrak/vue-offline in my vue ionic app when i install this plugin I got this error

```
vue-offline.js?bf4e:193 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$offlineStorage' of undefined
    at Object.install (vue-offline.js?bf4e:193)
    at Object.use (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2945)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:139)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1308)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1644)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:994
```

I checked  `vue-offline.js` file and got to know that  this was because of these lines

```
 if (pluginOptions.storage) Vue.prototype.$offlineStorage = VueOfflineStorage;
    if (pluginOptions.mixin) Vue.mixin(VueOfflineMixin);
```

Whole function was like this

```
var VueOfflinePlugin = {
  install: function install(Vue) {
    var options = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {
      mixin: true,
      storage: true
    };
    var pluginOptions = {
      mixin: options.mixin,
      storage: options.storage
    };
    if (pluginOptions.storage) Vue.prototype.$offlineStorage = VueOfflineStorage;
    if (pluginOptions.mixin) Vue.mixin(VueOfflineMixin);
  }
};
```

I am using in my main.js file

```
const app = createApp(AppMain)
    .use(IonicVue)
    .use(router)
    .use(RouterPrefetch)
    .use(VueOffline)
    .use(store);
```

What i am missing in this process?

Answer (score 0):

As of v2.0.8, `vue-offline` only supports Vue 2, but your Ionic app requires Vue 3.

There's an open GitHub issue ([`vue-offline#24`](https://github.com/filrak/vue-offline/issues/24)) that requests Vue 3 support. You could bump that issue, or create your own pull request that upgrades the plugin (see [Vue 3 Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html)).